# Test results for skipped tests - cucumber and webdriver io

Tags: cucumber, webdriver-io, allure

I am using allure to generate my test report and I noticed I had no "skipped" tests being reported - I knew I had some skipped tests.  Digging through the code, the skipped tests are not being run (which is correct) but there is no result being generated.  I was sure that using mocha I would still get a result file for skipped tests.

I am using the latest (as of now) webdriverio plugin as well as cucumber 7.0.0

Does anyone know if there is a way to "force" a result to be created for a skipped test?